# How to know if checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am looking for a solution to this matter for the last 2 hours and I can't find a simple answer to resolve it.

I want to check if the checkbox is checked or not and whatever I do, the console always tell me it is unchecked.

HTML :

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="option1" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="0" id="itemOrder-checkbox1">With option 1 (+$2)</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="option2" ng-true-value="3" ng-false-value="0" id="itemOrder-checkbox2">With option 2 (+$3)</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="option3" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" id="itemOrder-checkbox3">With option 3 (+$1)</ion-checkbox>
      <label class="item item-input" id="itemOrder-input4">
        <input id="notes" type="text" placeholder="Add some notes...">
      </label>
      <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 33px;"></div>
      <button class="button button-block button-dark" style="color:#F5E124;" type="submit" id="itemOrder-button3" ng-click="addToCart()">
          Add to cart (${{quantity * (15 + option1 + option2 + option3)}})
      </button>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.addToCart = function(){
    if ($scope.option1) {
        console.log("CheckBox is checked.");
    } else {
        console.log("CheckBox is not checked.");
    }

    firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId + '/cart/').push({
      item: "item1",
      quantity: document.getElementById('quantity').value,
      price: document.getElementById('price').textContent,
      notes: document.getElementById('notes').value,

    })
  $state.go("menu2.menu");
  }
```

Comment: use ng-change and update

Comment: Hello, I am new to this, can you please write me the code for this, I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: check the demo i showed in your previous question, it has the answer

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.CheckPassport = function () {
                if ($scope.HasPassport) {
                    $window.alert("CheckBox is checked.");
                } else {
                    $window.alert("CheckBox is not checked.");
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Do you have Passport?
        <label for="chkPassport">
            <input id="chkPassport" type="checkbox" ng-model="HasPassport" />
        </label>
        <input type="button" value = "Check Passport" ng-click = "CheckPassport()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked ng-change="click()" ng-model="option1" value="Bike">
    I have a bike
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.click = function(){
    if ($scope.option1) {
        alert("CheckBox is checked.");
    } else {
        alert("CheckBox is not checked.");
    }
  }
```

Here is the demo: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KNBPw826WRNAwQFDDdJt?p=preview)